# Modelling rnbinom not returning pre-set parameters

Tags: r, modeling, negative-binomial-distribution

I am working with the `rnbinom` function in R but I think I have misunderstood the meaning of the parameters that get stipulated in the arguments.

For reference, I have been looking at the documentation here: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/NegBinomial.html

I have generated a random vector like so:

`z <- rnbinom(500000, 0.16, 0.19)`

My understanding is that I have called for `500000` random values from a negative binomial distribution with a dispersion (theta) parameter of `0.16`. For the `prob` argument I entered `0.19`, which is defined as "*probability of success in each trial. 0 < prob <= 1.*" I have interpreted this argument as setting an "effect size" that would be returned if the simulated data is fit back into a negative binomial regression model. However, my understanding is evidently wrong. Please see the below for a step-by-step.

---

Load libraries

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(MASS)
```

When I plot the vector it looks like this:

```
hist(z)
```

[image]

Based on this histogram, the randomly generated vector is then transformed into a 2-column dataframe where the original values act as Xs and the frequencies act as Ys, like so:

```
dat <- data.frame(z=z,freq=as.vector(table(z)[as.character(z)]))
```

Rename columns:

```
colnames(dat) <- c("X","Y")
```

Plotting this X-Y dataframe looks like this:

```
g1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = z, y = freq))+
  geom_point(alpha = .2)+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(x = "X", y = "Y")
g1
```

[image]

Then, I attempt to fit this dataframe back into a negative binomial regression model:

```
M0 <- glm.nb(Y ~ X, data = dat)
summary(M0)
```

But I get this error:

```
Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values
In addition: Warning message:
glm.fit: fitted rates numerically 0 occurred
```

What is happening here? I had expected the model to return a regression coefficient of `0.19` as I stipulated in the original random vector generation.

Comment: May I suggest a somewhat easier way of setting up `dat`? Try `dat <- data.frame(z=z,freq=as.vector(table(z)[as.character(z)]))`.

Comment: That is much neater, thanks! I'll edit the code in the post. Unfortunately still stuck on the modelling issue though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unclear why you believe you need to supply `dat` to `glm.nb()`. The easiest way of setting up a model with no predictors would be simply

```
> model <- glm.nb(z~1)
```

We can now inspect it:

```
> coef(model)
(Intercept) 
 -0.3807305 
> model$theta
[1] 0.160006
```

So the `theta` output matches the 0.16 you put in. What does the estimated intercept of -0.3807 have to do with your 0.19?

First, note that we did not give the `link` parameter to `glm.nb()`, so it used the default link function, which is the log.

```
> exp(coef(model))
(Intercept) 
   0.683362
```

Second, note that `glm.nb()` uses a particular one of the many, many parameterizations of the negbin distribution (I recommend [Hilbe's *Negative Binomial Regression*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B010WERRU4)). Specifically, it models the mean (on the log scale). Let's verify:

```
> mean(z)
[1] 0.683362
```

This looks good.

So, how do we recover your 0.19? Since you didn't name the parameters you gave to `rnbinom()`, it by default fed your arguments `500000, 0.16, 0.19` into its first three parameters: `n=500000, size=0.16, prob=0.19`. A look at `?rnbinom` tells us that the mean of your random numbers should be `size*(1-prob)/prob`. Let's check:

```
> size <- 0.16
> prob <- 0.19
> size*(1-prob)/prob
[1] 0.6821053
```

This again looks good. So all we have to do is to solve this equation for the mean which `glm.nb()` fitted (on a log scale) to recover your `prob` parameter:

```
> model$theta/(exp(coef(model))+model$theta)
(Intercept) 
  0.1889737
```